# Unity3d, Currently selected scripting backend (.NET) is not installed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have a regular Unity3d project where I created a simple First-Person moving "Game". I recently discovered how to use unity and put an app on to a Xbox One developer console using Universal Windows Platform. However, when I go to build my game as a windows store app, it says

*"Currently selected scripting backend (.NET) is not installed."* Does anyone know how to fix this and/or download the Unity .NET scripting backend?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I hit the same problem and this is actually an optional component from the Unity installer. So run the installer assistant again and make sure .Net Scripting Backend is ticked.

[image]

Comment: I don't have this option but UWP instead. And it fixed the problem! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to install .NET 4.5, judging from [the doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/windowsstore-dotnet.html). [Win10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) is also required. You can install it via the Visual Studio Installer of VS2017.

> The .NET Scripting Backend is using Microsofts .NET to power scripting. Unlike other Unity platforms, Windows Store is not using .NET 3.5 Class Libraries profile, but rather a subset of .NET 4.5.

Also check if you have installed the Xbox One module is loaded: at *Menu/BuildSettings*, select *Platform/Xbox One*.

[Tips and Tricks for Building for UWP and deploying to Xbox One](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/tips-and-tricks-for-building-for-uwp-and-deploying-to-xbox-one.395150/)

Comment: I don't have the module loaded, but it gives me a broken download link

Comment: http://download.unity3d.com/download_unity/960ebf59018a/TargetSupportInstaller/UnitySetup-XboxOne-Support-for-Editor-5.3.5f1.exe

Comment: See [this thread](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1192663/xboxone-support-for-editor-535f1exe.html?_ga=1.3016560.1328060710.1489118549).

Comment: I just recently downloaded Visual Studio 2017 and have been using it with Unity. Does this process require me to have Visual Studio 2015 also?

Comment: I don't think VS2015 is required. Just try it.

Comment: Tried installing .NET 4.5 and it said I already have it installed

Comment: Thank you so much for recommending that I use VS 2015! It worked!